# "N-1" Cumulative Averages

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data = data.frame(patient_id = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2), 
age = c(43, 43, 44, 44, 21, 21, 21), 
gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"), 
appointment_number = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3), 
missed = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

**My Question:** Grouped by each ID, I want to create two variables:

- The first variable takes the value of the previous appointment value
- The second variable takes the "n-1" cumulative average of the previous appointment values (e.g. If patient_id = 1 has 8 rows, the cumulative average at this row would be the cumulative average of the first 7 rows)

Here is my attempt to do this:

```
my_data_final <- my_data %>% 
  group_by(patient_id) %>% 
  mutate(cummean = cumsum(missed)/(row_number() - 1)) %>% 
  mutate(previous_apt = lag(missed))
```

This results in the cummean variable being greater than 1, even though the variable in question can only be 1 or 0:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 7
# Groups:   patient_id [2]
  patient_id   age gender appointment_number missed cummean previous_apt
       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
1          1    43 M                       1      0 NaN               NA
2          1    43 M                       2      0   0                0
3          1    44 M                       3      1   0.5              0
4          1    44 M                       4      1   0.667            1
5          2    21 F                       1      1 Inf               NA
6          2    21 F                       2      1   2                1
7          2    21 F                       3      1   1.5              1
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

**Note:** I tried to resolve this - is this correct?

```
 my_data %>% 
    group_by(patient_id) %>% 
    mutate(previous_apt = lag(missed)) %>% 
    mutate(cummean = (cumsum(missed) - missed) / (row_number() - 1)) %>%  mutate(previous_apt_2 = lag(missed, 2))
```

Comment: If it gives the result you expected, it's correct. :-)

Comment: The quotes around your numbers make me think you need to do a class conversion to `numeric`. And it seems strange to me that you have `row_number() - 1` in the denominator... dividing the first row by 0. Maybe you want to `lag()` your `cummean` result instead? Also `dplyr` provides a `cummean` function so you don't have to roll your own. But thelatemail gets correctly to the point - run your function on your data, pick out a few test cases and make sure the result looks right. We usually ask people for desired output to go along with sample input. What's your desired output for this data??

Comment: @ Gregor Thomas: I updated my question to be more clear - can you please take a look at it? thank you!

Comment: @ thelatemail: it is not giving me the expected result :)

Comment: @stats_noob Do you need `library(slider);library(dplyr); my_data %>% group_by(patient_id) %>% mutate(Cummean = slide_dbl(missed, .f = ~ mean(head(.x, -1)), .before = n()), previous_apt = lag(missed)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun: thank you for your reply! Should your code produce the same result as mine?

Comment: @stats_noob yes, it is giving the same output as your last code block